# Limit insert in column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can I limit the maximum times a string can be inserted in a column in MySQL. If it reaches the maximum amount, it moves to the next. For an example if 1 is entered 3 times it moves to 2.
Like 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4..... and so on.

Comment: You have to check their counts on every insert first and then write logic to insert accordingly

Comment: By counting first, or by using a trigger (I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lacks some information but I'll try.

First, in order to test the occurrence of the inserted string, I think you can use the SELECT statement : 
`SELECT COUNT(myLimitedColumn) FROM myTable WHERE myLimitedColumn=${myInputString}`

So that if the result is equal to 3, well I let you handle the behaviour in this case, but if the input is **1** then if its occurrence equals 3, as you said move to the next, **2**, and try again. 
And if the occurrence is inferior to 3, you can insert.